# Enviar imagem via POST no angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

AJUDA.
estou tentando enviar uma imagem para um web service via POST.
no postman testei e funcionou
[image: teste no postman]

no meu controller fiz assim

```
$scope.upload = function (files) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('imagem', files[0]);
        midanaAPI.cadastrarImagem(fd).success(
                function (data) {
                    if (data.Status) {
                        $scope.foto = data.UrlImage;
                    }else {
                        $scope.mensagemErro = "Não foi possível carregar a Imagem, tente novamente.";
                    }
                });
    }
```

este midanaAPI.cadastrarImagem(fd) está chamando o meu service, segue o código

```
var _cadastrarImagem = function (imagem) {
    var data = 'Foto='+imagem;
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined,
            'Device': "midayas.Device",
            'Token': "midayas.Token"
        }
    };
    return $http.post(configValor.baseUrl + "Upload/File", data, config);
};
```

só que Web Service não encontra nenhum arquivo na requisição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solucionado...
era só besteira.
em vez de imagem o servidor estava esperando Foto então a linha
 fd.append('imagem', files[0]);
ficou assim 
 fd.append('Foto', files[0]);